# Generating Random Numbers within a range

Tags: c++, random, int, range, parentheses

So, i'm attempting to generate a random number between 1 and 61 using an overloaded parenthetical operator, however for some reason every time I run my code, I keep getting the same result of 49.

Here's what I have:

```
double operator()() const {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> _uniformIntDistribution(1, 61);
    std::default_random_engine _generator;

    double result;    
    result = _uniformIntDistribution(_generator);  

    return result;
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, if you create the same random number generator, with the same starting seed, every time, what did you expect? You need to create the random number generator ***once***, and merely call it, each time.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Wait, where am I setting the seed? I'm confused. Wherever it is, it is definitely unintentional

Comment: @NomOnTheCookie you **can't fail** to set the seed of a `std::default_random_engine`. Your default constructed `_generator` has a default seed

Answer (score 0):

Compiler will use default seed each time it compiles and that means that you will have the same sequence of random numbers. Depending on requirements to your program and how "random" you need your numbers to be, you can use system current time value as a seed. That way each time you compile, random engine output will change. Here is link : [Notice member function "seed"](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/default_random_engine/)

Comment: Using time as seed is really bad practice, please don't

Comment: That is what i have read in books and forums. Can you elaborate  on why is bad? It might help people with similar questions a bit more. Thank you

Comment: The problem is quite involved, but even in the best scenario, you get numbers that isn't "random" enough. See [this](http://www.pcg-random.org/predictability.html) for more